# Programa pra achar o MMC em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tava fazendo um exercício básico para a função `While`, ele pedia para criar um programa que achasse o MMC entre 2 números... eu consegui fazer, mas o programa continua imprimindo a resposta sem parar em *loop*. Onde eu errei?

```
num1 = int(input("Digite um número inteiro:"))
num2 = int(input("Digite outro número inteiro:"))

if num1 > num2:
    maior = num1
else:
    maior = num2
while True:
    if maior % num1 == 0 and maior % num2 == 0:
        print(maior)
    else:
        maior += 1
```

Comment: Talvez um break ao achar o número desejado? Logo depois do print?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Sim, funciona, mas o livro ainda não ensinou esse break: então deve ter alguma maneira de fazer sem isso

Comment: Então bota como condição de parada, no lugar de fazer laço infinito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode simplismente adicionar um `break` após imprimir sua variável "maior", assim ele vai interomper o while. Dessa forma:

```
num1 = int(input("Digite um número inteiro:"))
num2 = int(input("Digite outro número inteiro:"))

if num1 > num2:
    maior = num1
else:
    maior = num2
while True:
    if maior % num1 == 0 and maior % num2 == 0:
        print(maior)
        break
    else:
        maior += 1
```

Espero ter ajudado.

**EDIT:**
Como você disse que ainda não viu `break` tente fazer dessa forma com um laço `for` que irá deixar seu código até mais "limpo".

```
num1 = int(input("Digite um número inteiro:"))
num2 = int(input("Digite outro número inteiro:"))

if num1 > num2:
    maior = num1
else:
    maior = num2

for i in range(maior):
    aux = num1 * i
    if (aux % num2) == 0:
        mmc = aux

print(mmc)
```

Espero ter ajudado amigo.

Comment: Funciona desse jeito, mas não tem como fazer isso sem o break? O livro que fez o exercício ainda não tinha ensinado o 'break', então deve ter.

Comment: @Mateus tem, eu fiz.

Comment: @Mateus fiz as alterações, da uma olhada.

Comment: @VictorNogueira , essa solução iterativa parecia um forçar o `break`. Isso funciona mesmo em Python? Pelo que me lembre, o `for` do Python funciona sobre geradores, então ele deveria simplesmente ignorar alterações ao valor de `i`

Comment: sim, @JeffersonQuesado foi um equivoco, essa linha é irrelevante. vou editar.

Comment: Para a entrada `4,6`, a saída deveria ser 12. Confere?

Answer (score 3):

Já agora uma versão preguiçosa e ineficiente: calcular os múltiplos comuns em [a..a*b] e selecionar o primeiro...

```
[x for x in range(a,a*b+1) if x%b==0 and x%a==0][0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu acho que este código está errado, mas se for para fazer assim, então faça desta forma:

```
num1 = int(input("Digite um número inteiro:"))
num2 = int(input("Digite outro número inteiro:"))
maior = num1 if num1 > num2 else num2
while maior % num1 != 0 or maior % num2 != 0:
    maior += 1
print(maior)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/8y5Xlo). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rsoqcpxz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Math/Mmc.py).

Comment: No caso, a condição negada.

Comment: Teste, entrada 2 e 3; resultado esperado 6; ao entrar no laço, `3 % 2` vai ser diferente de zero, então o valor de `maior` não vai ser alterado, será retornado 3

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado como eu disse, esse código está esquisito demais, eu respondi só o que era o foco da pergunta que é acabar com o *loop* infinito e sem usar `break` que é horrível.

Comment: Também acho que a atribuição condicional está estranha... não seria `maior = num1 if num1>num2 else num2`?

Comment: Eu faria a solução do @MrGhost, mas essa incremental, apesar de ineficiente, geraria o resultado correto.

Comment: Arrumei esses deslizes.

Comment: Se fosse uma solução simples talvez, parece estar no caminho correto, mas não acho que precisa de tudo aquilo.

Answer (score 2):

Realmente oque estava causando esse **loop** foi a condição `while True:` dessa forma não tem nenhum parâmetro que diga para o Python que essa condição poderá ser **false** e sempre irá rodar o script. Segue um exemplo aqui sem o uso do **break** espero que sirva para seu propósito:

```
mdc = num1
i = num2

resto = None
while resto is not 0:
    resto = mdc % i
    mdc  = i
    i  = resto

resp = (mdc * i) / mdc
print("Resultado: "+str(resp))
```

Comment: Chama `x` de `mdc` e tudo fica menos obscuro

Comment: Opa valeu amigo, boa observação.

Comment: Para quem não conhece, essa é a adaptação do [Algoritmo de Euclides](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Euclides?wprov=sfti1) para calcular o MMC. Isso funciona porque `num1 * num2 = mmc * mdc`

Answer (score 1):

Vi essa pergunta e fiz essa função, a vantagem é que ela recebe uma lista de numeros, e o MMC pode ser calculado para além de 2 números.

```
def mmc(nums):
    max_ = max(nums)
    i = 1
    while True:
        mult = max_ * i
        if all(mult%nr == 0 for nr in nums):
            return mult
        i += 1

>>> mmc([5, 6, 8])
>>> 120
```