# Criação de variáveis

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como crio uma variável e adiciono o tipo como inteira, mas sem ter nenhum valor definido? Preciso dessa variável para fazer isso:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
x = int # tentei colocar o tipo da variável como inteira dessa forma, mas dá erro.
if a * x == b: # a variável x precisa ser um número qualquer e inteiro para que funcione com o "if".
    print(f'O MMC entre {a} e {b} é {a}.')
```

Comment: Veja a pergunta [Programa pra achar o MMC em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/237169/5878). Se sua pergunta está assim e você resolveu da maneira que comentou, com resto de divisão por 2, simplesmente nada fez sentido e por isso votei para fechar a pergunta como não clara.

Comment: Lucas seria isto https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/263153/3635 o que precisa?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 2):

Dá erro porque Python é uma linguagem dinamicamente tipada, não existem tipos, todas as variáveis podem ser qualquer coisa.

Na verdade o código nem faz sentido porque `x` não tem valor algum e não deveria ser usada para nada.

Coloque um valor na variável e pronto.

Duvido que fará a lógica ser correta, mas compilará e executará sem erros, aí vê o que quer fazer com a lógica.

Comment: Se eu der um valor qualquer para x eu não vou ter resolvido meu problema, não existe nenhuma forma de representar x ?

Comment: Algo sem valor também não pode ser usado, e isto é matemática, não é o Python. Se você precisa resolver um problema sem um valor, o problema não é resolvível.

Comment: Consegui fazer usando o resto da divisão dos dois números.